# Nebular theme installation issue in angular 14

Tags: angular, npm

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: dashboard.cashand.in@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@14.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^14.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/animations@"^13.0.0" from @nebular/theme@9.1.0-rc.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@nebular/theme
npm ERR!   @nebular/theme@"9.1.0-rc.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Answer (score 0):

you are using angular 14 but nebular supports only angular 13 at the moment.
Either us `--force` when installing Nebular or downgrade to version 13